# Finding largest and second largest numbers in a loop

Tags: python

I recently have started to learn how to code with python.
In this code I want to find the largest and second largest inputted number (the age of faculty members of a university).
However it does not work and I do not know where the problem is.

```
oldest = 0
oldest2 = 0
for i in range (100):
    age = int(input())
    if age > oldest :
        oldest = age
    age = int(input())
    if age > oldest2 and age < oldest: 
        oldest2 = age
  
    if age == -1:
        break
print (oldest, oldest2)
```

Comment: "It does not work!" How does it not work? What is your current output (given a certain input), and what do you expect as output? Please make your question complete.

Comment: @00 I support your attempt to make this a better question, but it doesn't require expected output to realize why this code would fail.  It's quite obvious, really.

Comment: @MarkRansom Yes, that is perhaps a minor detail, but good practice overall. It fits nicely with the other requirements.

Comment: @00 given how many times you've tried to get this right, maybe it wasn't as obvious as I thought!

Answer (score 1):

You are getting ages twice per loop and only considering one of the two options for each. At best you could be half right. Instead, let python do the work for you. You can gather the ages into a list, sort and then pull the numbers.

```
ages = []
while True:
    next_val = int(input())
    if nex_val == -1:
        break
    ages.append(next_val)
ages.sort()
print(ages[-2:])
```

Comment: I might be wrong here but I would assume that as this is a beginner they might have it as an exercise to actually implement this

Comment: This changes the functionality. How could they short circuit and exit before 100 ages are entered? Also this doesn't explain why you used the code that you did, or what things like `[-2:]` mean. This is a pretty beginner question so I'd focus on explaining why rather than just saying "do this and it'll work".

Comment: @RandomDavis - Fixed the early exit. lists, sort and slice are all extremely basic python that should be an early part of learning. I did tell the user what was wrong but didn't think that simply fiddling with the existing code was the best way to go. You can post a fix to the existing code as another example of what to do.

Comment: @Tomerikoo - But as an exercise, shouldn't we apply the basic tool sets that are available?

Comment: I will be the last to argue with that. It's just that often around here people come with restrictions by teachers/exercises. I completely agree with you that those restrictions make no sense because a good programmer should know how to use tools already available to them. You might argue that it's good practice to implement from zero... ;)

Answer (score 0):

The following should work. It is only a slight variation to what you have already. Are you looking for the optimal way to achieve your result or do you have a specific set of requirements?

```py
oldest = 0
oldest2 = 0
for i in range (100):
    age = int(input())
    if age > oldest:
        oldest2 = oldest
        oldest = age
    elif age > oldest2 and age != oldest:
        oldest2 = age

    # This is in case you have faculty members that are all the same age
    # We assume none of them are age 0
    if oldest2 == 0:
        oldest2 = oldest

    if age == -1:
        break
print (oldest, oldest2)
```

With the following as test data

```
[10, 20, 40, 20, 5]
[10, 90, 40, 20, 5]
[100, 100, 90]
[30, 30]
```

the results are

```
[40, 20]
[90, 40]
[100, 90]
[30, 30]
```

Comment: Your last test for `oldest2 == 0` assumes there is more than one input.

Comment: Thank you so much that was really helpful.

Comment: I can not unserstand the differences between following 2 codes

Comment: @MarkRansom If there is only one input, say 29, the output will be 29, 29. As `oldest2` will be 0 it will then be set to the same value as `oldest`. Of course don't know if that is desired behaviour as it is not stated above.

Comment: @elhamzohrehvand which following two code, mine and yours?

Comment: @Stu  sorry I meant (your code) and ( your code without elif command)

Comment: My assumption without instructions to the contrary would be that with only one input, there would only be one output.

Comment: @elhamzohrehvand When the `elif` is reached we know `age` is not greater than `oldest`. So we first check is age greater than `oldest2`, because if it is then this must be the second oldest age, except, however, if `age` is the same as `oldest`. It makes `[100, 90, 100]` become `[100, 90]`, without it would be `[100, 100]`. What is your desired outcome for when there is only one input?

Comment: @Stu  Thank you so much! I totally understand it now. There are more than one faculty!

Comment: As you can see from your test examples your code fails at actually doing the job. The second last example should return [100, 100], since those are the two largest instances of age.

Comment: Maybe @PixelRayn, I interpreted "largest and second largest inputted number" as meaning two different numbers. If the question had of said "two largest" then I would have gone for `[100, 100]`. As you can see, I mention in a comment above to the OP about the `[100, 100]` and `[100, 90]` results.

Answer (score 0):

```
first_oldest = 0
second_oldest = 0

while True:

    age = int(input())
    if age != -1:

        if age > first_oldest:
            second_oldest = first_oldest
            first_oldest = age

        elif second_oldest < age < first_oldest:
            second_oldest = age

        if second_oldest == 0:
            second_oldest = first_oldest
    else:
        break

print(first_oldest, second_oldest)
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried not to change your code too much, though I can literally code what you want with 6 or 8 lines of code. this is why I am not going to give you the 6 or 8 line of code I am going to leave it to you to challenge your python skills and improve it and it might just be a little to complex idk if this what you are really going for but that what made sense for me by reading you code.

````
oldest = 0
oldest2 = 0
for i in range(2):
    age = int(input("enter age"))
    if age > oldest:
        oldest = age

    second_age = int(input("enter age"))
    if second_age > oldest2 :
        oldest2 = second_age

    if age <= 0:
        print("there is no such age for a human")
        break
        

if oldest != 0 and oldest2 != 0:
    print(f"oldest age is:{oldest} \n second oldest age is: {oldest2}")```
````

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple approaches here, some are faster, some are more expressive. I will use two approaches here.

Let's define a function that will take a list of integers, find the two largest numbers and return them as a tupil.

In the first approach we sort the list from low to high and return the last two numbers:

```
def get_largest(input):
    input.sort()
    return input[-1], input[-2]
```

The second approach is to walk over all numbers and check whether they are larger then the last largest number you found.

Since you only expect positive numbers we can set our baseline to 0

```
def get_largest(input):

    oldest = 0
    second_oldest = 0
    
    for age in input:
        
        if age >= oldest:
            second_oldest = oldest
            oldest = age
        elif age > second_oldest:
            second_oldest = age

    return oldest, second_oldest
```

Now you can write a function that gets an input list. I will assume, that the user only enters valid numbers:

```
def get_input():

    input_list = list() # Creates am empty list

    input_str = ""

    while input_str != "-1": # This only works in python
        input_str = input("In: ")
        input_list.append(int(input_str))

    return input_list
```